# Can we use Windows *.icon (icon) files to Wine apps?

Tags: icons

As all we know, Windows software has its own icons, normally as a *.icon file into the app directory.

Is there a way to use these Windows *.icon files (graphic images) as the icon image of the Wine apps?

How?